# Problem Using Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick

Tags: factoring

> Megan is jealous of her older sister's $a\times b$ inch Zac Efron
>   poster, so she cuts out a rectangle around his face, which has
>   dimensions $\frac{a}{2}-2$ by  $\frac{b}{3}-5$, and steals it. Megan's
>   older sister decides she's over Zac Efron anyways, and uses the rest
>   of the paper as wrapping paper. She wraps an $11$-inch cube, wasting
>   no paper, and has $3$ square inches leftover. If $a$ and $b$ are
>   integers and $b>a$, and the difference between the length and width of
>   the poster is less than $50$, find the dimensions of the poster.
>
> Express your answer as the ordered pair $(a,b)$.

I don't really know how to start this problem. Any solutions would be awesome.

Comment: Hint: Start by calculating the surface area of an 11-inch cube, and adding 3.

Comment: Well, I know that is 729.

Comment: Hint: what is the area equation for the original area expressed in terms of the removed area together with the wrapped cube and remaining area?

Comment: @TheLeogend I added a nice table. Any questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The key to such tasks is to extract the mathematical information:

> Megan is jealous of her older sister's $a\times b$ inch Zac Efron
>   poster,

The poster is a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$. And implicitly: $a, b > 0$.

> so she cuts out a rectangle around his face, which has
>   dimensions $\frac{a}{2}-2$ by  $\frac{b}{3}-5$, and steals it.

The cut part is a rectangle with sides $a/2 -2$ and $b/3-5$.

> Megan's
>   older sister decides she's over Zac Efron anyways, and uses the rest
>   of the paper as wrapping paper. She wraps an $11$-inch cube, wasting
>   no paper, and has $3$ square inches leftover.

$$
A_{\text{poster}} - A_{\text{cut}} = A_{\text{cube}} + 3 \, \text{inch}^2 \\
a_{\text{cube}} = 11 \, \text{inch}
$$

> If $a$ and $b$ are
>   integers and $b>a$,

$$
a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \\
a < b
$$

> and the difference between the length and width of
>   the poster is less than $50$,

$$
\lvert a - b \rvert < 50
$$

> find the dimensions of the poster.
>
> Express your answer as the ordered pair $(a,b)$.

We can easily calculate the three areas and end up with a conic equation of the type
$$
A x^2 + B x y + C y^2 + D x + E y = F
$$
and the inequalities,
$$
a, b > 0 \\
a < b \\
b - a < 50
$$
Due to the integer constraints there should be a finite set of solutions.

**Hint:**

If there is no easier way, the title seems a bit suspicious, the systematic approach seems to transform ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Conversion_to_canonical_form), [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kegelschnitt#Allgemeine_Kegelschnittgleichung)) the quadratic form to a Pell-type equation ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation))
$$
X^2 - D Y^2 = N
$$
which can be solved by continued fractions, if I remember correctly. And then weed out some solutions by those inequalities.

**Update:**

Yes, the title was suspicious. See this video ([link](https://youtu.be/0nN3H7w2LnI)).

So SFFT reminds me somewhat of "completing the square":
\begin{align}
5 ab + 15 a + 4b &= 4434 \iff \\
5a (b+3) + 4b &= 4434 \iff \\
5a (b+3) + 4b + 4\cdot3 &= 4434 + 4\cdot 3 \iff \\
5a (b+3) + 4(b+3) &= 4446 \iff \\
(5a+4)(b+3) &= 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19
\end{align}

This will now give the opportunity to assign the $N=5$ factors to each of the $M=2$ factors in parentheses on the left hand side:
\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc|c}
5a+4 & b+3 & 5a+4 & b+3 & a & b & \text{constraints OK} \\
\hline 
2  & 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 2 & 2223 & ! &     & \\
3  & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 3 & 1482 & ! &     &  \\
13 & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 13 & 342 & ! &     & \\
19 & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 19 & 234 & 3 & 231 & \text{no}, \Delta < 50 \\
\hline
2  \cdot 3  & 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 6   & 741 & ! &     & \\
2  \cdot 13 & 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 26  & 171 & ! &     & \\
2  \cdot 19 & 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 38  & 117 & ! &     & \\
3  \cdot 3  & 2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 9   & 494 & 1 & 491 & \text{no}, \Delta < 50 \\
3  \cdot 13 & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 39  & 114 & 7 & 111 & \text{no}, \Delta < 50 \\
3  \cdot 19 & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 57  & 78  & ! &     & \\
13 \cdot 19 & 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3   & 247 & 18  & ! &     & \\
\hline
3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 2  \cdot 3  & 741 & 6   & !  &    & \\
3 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 2  \cdot 13 & 171 & 26  & !  &    & \\
3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 2  \cdot 19 & 117 & 38  & !  &    & \\
2 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 3  \cdot 3  & 494 & 9   & 98 & 6  & \text{no}, a < b \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 3  \cdot 13 & 114 & 39  & 22 & 36 & \text{yes} \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 3  \cdot 19 & 78  & 57  & !  &    & \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3   & 13 \cdot 19 & 18  & 247 & !  &    & \\
\hline 
3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 2  & 2223 &  2 &   & !  & \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 3  & 1482 &  3 &   & !  & \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 19  & 13 & 342  & 13 & ! &    & \\
2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13  & 19 & 234  & 19 & 46 & 16 & \text{no}, a < b \\
\end{array}